# Set Theory Proof: Valid or not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I'm trying to gain understanding of set proofs and I came across this one. I can't help but think the proof is too simple and that there is more to it.

Problem: Prove or disprove for arbitrary sets $A$, $B$, $C$

$A\subset B\Rightarrow (A\cap C\subset B\cap C)$

My proof is:

Let $x$ be an arbitrary element

1) $\{x\mid (x\in A \rightarrow x\in B)\rightarrow [(x\in A \wedge x\in C)\rightarrow (x\in B\wedge x\in C)]\}$
by definition of subset and intersection

2) $\{x \mid (x\in A\rightarrow x\in B) \rightarrow (x\in A\rightarrow x\in B)\}$ by Simplification

3) $\{x \mid A\subset B \rightarrow A\subset B\}$ by definition of subset

QED

Would this be a valid proof for this particular problem? If not, how come?

Comment: I don't understand your notation in 1, 2, and 3.  Usually set theorists (and mathematicians in general) use { ... | ... } to mean a particular set, which is like a mathematical *object*; in a proof, you need to be writing *statements* (about mathematical objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite follow your proof, it looks like you end by stating the trivial fact that $A \subset B \implies A \subset B$. This does not establish that $A\subset B \implies A\cap C \subset B \cap C$. I would prove this result by doing the following:

Let $x \in A\cap C$. This means $x \in A$ and $x \in C$. Since $A \subset B$ then $x \in B$, so $x\in B \cap C$. The result follows.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that $A\cap C=A-C^c$ and $B\cap C = B-C^c$.

$$A\subset B\Rightarrow A-C^c\subset B-C^c \Rightarrow A\cap C\subset B\cap C$$